# Obtain map routes as connected graph

Tags: here-api

Can I download from here.com API all roads in USA as connected graph? I didn't find any api method for this, only download map images.

```
https://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/mapview?c=52.5159%2C13.3777&z=14&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't think we have such a product as a REST API currently. Perhaps reach out to our customer support group to license the raw RDF data?